# A ring is a divison ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm confused with the following exercise:

Prove or disprove: Let $(R,+ , \cdot)$ a ring having the property that for each $a\not=0, \ b\in R$, there exist $r\in R$ such that $a\cdot r=b$, then $R$ is a divison ring.

Since $a$ and $b$ are not necessarily different, there exist $r_0\in R$, such that $a\cdot r_0 = a$, but this doesn't mean that $r_0$ is unique or $r_0\cdot a=a$, that's because I think the statement is false, but I can't think in a counterexample. Am I right? and there is a counterexample, or is the statement true?

Comment: One of the axioms for a ring is the existence of a (two sided) unit for multiplication.

Comment: Do your rings come with a $1$, or not necessarily?

Comment: @coffeemath: As you know, that varies from author to author.

Comment: You are correct that just knowing that $ax=a$ in a ring does not tell you that $xa=a$ or that $bx=b$ for all $b$. But that is not the only thing you know here, so you still have work to  do.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin no, in my textbook rings don't have a unit necessarily

Comment: Because that is not a universal convention, you should state this up front (this is true in general when talking about rings, if you want to avoid misunderstandings; you should specify if you assume rings are unital or not).

Comment: Note that the zero ring satisfies this condition.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You're right. The text I used called it a rng in case a 1 was not assumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can prove existence of unique and universal 1 provided there exists at least one $a\neq 0$.

First we prove (by contradiction) that there are no zero divisors. Assume $\exists u,v: uv=0 \wedge u\neq 0 \wedge v\neq 0$. Then  $\exists r,q : ur=u, r=vq$. But then $u = ur=uvq=(uv)q = 0q=0$ -- q.e.d. Note: this also proves that $r$ is unique for a fixed $a$.

Next we can show that $r$ is a right-side multiplicative identity for all elements of $R$. I.e., if $\exists a : a\neq 0 \wedge ar=a$ then $\forall b: br=b$. Proof: if $b=0$ then $0r=0=b$. Now assume $b\neq 0$ and $br=c \neq b$. Then for some $q$ we have $c=bq$ which means $br=bq \rightarrow b(r-q)=0 \rightarrow r-q = 0$.

Now we can prove that $r$ acts as a multiplicative identity on both sides, i.e. $ra=ar=a$. Proof: $a^2 = (ar)a = a(ra) \rightarrow a(a - ra) = 0 \rightarrow a-ra = 0$

Comment: You need to assume that there exists $a\neq 0$ in the ring. If $R=\{0\}$, then it trivially satisfies the condition but is not a division ring (which requires $1\neq 0$).